# primefaces Tabclose event receives null tab in the listener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am generating dynamic tabs by clicking New tab button. Its a strange issue. I generated 3 tabs when i close the first tab we received closed tab but when i closed the second tab we received the null tab.

Here is the sample code

Xhtml Page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="cmdbutton" value="NewTab"
        actionListener="#{bean.buttonListener}" update=":tabView"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="false"
    widgetVar="tabViewVar">

    <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{bean.onTabClose}"
        partialSubmit="true" />

    <p:tab title="Godfather Part I">
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton id="cmdbutton12" value="button" update=":tabView"></p:commandButton>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <h:outputText value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone..." />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.dynamicTab}" var="tab">
        <p:tab id="#{tab.id}" binding="#{tab}"></p:tab>
    </c:forEach>
</p:tabView>
```

Bean:

```
    public class Bean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Tab> dynamicTab = new ArrayList<Tab>();


    public List<Tab> getDynamicTab() {
        return dynamicTab;
    }
    public void setDynamicTab(List<Tab> dynamicTab) {
        this.dynamicTab = dynamicTab;
    }
    public Bean() {
        super();
    }


    public void buttonListener(ActionEvent a){
        HtmlForm f=new HtmlForm();
        Tab tempTab = new Tab();
        String id="abc"+UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        tempTab.setId(id);
        tempTab.setTitle(id);
        tempTab.setClosable(true);
        tempTab.getChildren().add(f);
        dynamicTab.add(tempTab);
    }

    public void onTabClose(TabCloseEvent event) {
        Tab tab = event.getTab();
        dynamicTab.remove(tab);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [dataModel mode for dynamic tabs](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml) as priveded by the tabView component? `<p:tabView value="#{bean.dynamicTab}" var="tab"><p:tab title="#{tab.title}"></p:tab></p:tabView>` And you also seem to have a name clash in your usage of the variable `tab`:  `var="tab"` vs. `binding="#{tab}"` looks like a conflict to me.

Comment: As mentioned on the PF github its becase you are using `c:forEach` that is causing the issue.

Comment: HI @Melloware i tried by datamodel of tabview  **<p:tabView id="tabView" value="#{bean.dynamicTab}" var="tabvar"><p:tab binding="#{tabvar}" /> </p:tabView>** but its not working. can you please suggest any other way

Comment: Remove that `binding="#{tabvar}"`.   And elements in `#{bean.dynamicTab}` do not need to be of type `Tab`. They can be arbitrary entity types. Declar the `HtmlForm` in your xhtml using `h:form` element.

Comment: Hi @selaron the tabs are generated on the serer side. I need to display it on ui. I am not able to understand what you are pointing. Can you please post few lines of code.

Comment: He is saying use <h:form> in your XHTML instead of generating the Form in your Java code.

Comment: HI @Melloware The problem here is tab contents are dynamic . Can you please advice how to map the dynamic contents to Xhtml by any way. Example scenario is as follows. User click  new request button -> i created a tab in bean and then i need it add it to tabview. Here tab contents are dynamic depending on users and also one user can able to add any number of new request tabs. If its not possible with tabview can you guide any other component.